# Send struct over socket in C

Tags: c, serialization, client-server

I am developing a client/server program and my client has to send messages to the server.

**Sample message C structure**:

```
struct Registration
{
char multicastGroup[24];
pid_t clientPid;
};
```

**Client code snippet to serialize struct**

```
struct Registration regn ;
regn.clientPid = getpid();
strcpy(regn.multicastGroup, "226.1.1.1");

printf("PID:%d\n", regn.clientPid);        
printf("MG:%s\n", regn.multicastGroup);
printf("Size:%d\n", sizeof(regn));           //Size is 28

data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(regn));
memcpy(data, &regn, sizeof(regn));
printf("Size:%d\n", sizeof(data));           //Size is 4.
```

**Server code to de-serialize data**

```
if(recvfrom(sd, recvBuf, recvBufSize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &len) < 0)
{
       printf("Error receiving message from client\n");
}
else
{
       printf("Message received:%s\n", recvBuf);
       printf("Size :%d\n", strlen(recvBuf));
       memcpy(&regn, recvBuf, sizeof(regn));
       printf("PID:%d\n", regn.clientPid);
       printf("MG:%s\n", regn.multicastGroup);
}
```

After copying the struct to `unsigned char *`, the size of the array is only 4.
Why is data not fully copied to the array?

The server is not able to reconstruct the struct from the char array.
Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof(regn)` gives size of your complete structure `Registration`, wheras `sizeof(data)` is size of pointer on your machine that is 4 bytes (`data` should be pointer of `Registration` type).

In expression:

```
memcpy(data, &regn, sizeof(regn));
        ^     ^
        |     value variable of struct type 
        is pointer
```

also notice in printf, `.` is used to access elements e.g. `regn.multicastGroup`.

Comment: I want to send this data over the socket. Hence I am `memcpy` it to `unsigned char*`

Comment: @cppcoder which function you use, if it takes size of data stored then you are to use  `sizeof(struct Registration)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan In `sendto()` I replaced `sizeof(data)` with `sizeof(regn)` and it fixed the issue.

Comment: @sehe hey Sehe Thanks!, remember you :) you given a tricky answer that day in C++

Comment: @sehe Why [int `array[] = {}`;](http://codepad.org/Q3RNPv32) is valid code **?** I do not understand it **?**

Answer (score 4):

While the code will work if you send and recv on the same endian machine - your client and server should ideally perform a host to network endian conversion to maintain coherence when inspecting clientPid.

Comment: Can you show how to perform `htonl` on a variable while sending?