# how to receive the data from structure when you do not know which structure received

Tags: c, sockets, structure, protocols

I am developing the client server application in c in linux environment.
I used some communication protocols.
the client can send any of two structures below.

1)

```
typedef struct
{
  String userName;
} user;

typedef struct
{
  msgId = 20;
  user u1;
} msg1;
```

2)

```
typedef struct
{
  String mailId;
} mail;

typedef struct
{
  msgId = 30;
  mail m1;
} msg2;
```

now suppose client send the msg2 to the server , after filling the data to the structure.

> `write (socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&msg2, sizeof(msg2));`

at the server side , when I receive the structure

> `read (client_socket_fd, &a, sizeof(a)); // here I have written &a because I do not know which structure I received.`

so , how would I know what the structure is received at server side ?
please assist me , and if the question looks so dumb then please , suggest me to the article or name of the topic to read.
thank you.

Comment: what is `String`? remember that data you want to transfer has to be POD.

Answer (score 3):

This is where you should do serialization of message. Whatever be the structure you send from the client, it should be serialized to a stream of characters while sending over the network. Also, let the first element of the message be an identifier which lets the server know what structure it is.

Example to convert a structure into char buffer:

```
memcpy(data, &regn, sizeof(regn));  
regn - a struct
data - allocated char pointer
```

Beware that if your client and server exists in different platforms, you need to take care of endianness.

Check this link for more details

[Send struct over socket in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817280/send-struct-over-socket-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

The server needs to get the ID first before reading the rest of the message:-

```
read (socket_fd, &message_id, sizeof message_id);
switch (message_id)
{
case 20:
  read (socket_fd, &user, sizeof user);
  break;

case 30:
  read (socket_fd, &mail, sizeof mail);
  break;
}
```

Be careful to make sure the second read uses the size of the message without the prefixed ID field.

Comment: how can I make sure that ? please give me the idea.

Comment: @user2742399: on the server, the second read wouldn't read a msg1 structure inside the switch statement (for example), it would read a user struct because the msgIdin the msg1 structure has already been read by the first read statement before the switch.

Answer (score 1):

since you already have a id at first member. you may separately read the int? and then the payload dependent of that id. (you have to read the msgcontent typ since the id was already read.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch the msgId is what I put there in the body of all the messages I am  sending. Am I get you properly ?

Answer (score 1):

make the whole thing a struct containing a union:

```
union rcv
{
    struct msg1 m1;
    struct msg2 m2;
};

struct msg 
{
    int msg_id;
    union rcv msg;
};
```

Comment: i would suggest a top level struct that contains the id and then a union 'content' that contains all the data structures since the id does not belong to the data structures.

Comment: I already proposed that in my sample code above, but forgot to mention it in the text, thanks.

Comment: your union members are missing variable names. its confusing because op does not uses uppercase naming  convention